# Cannot access RowSpan property at run time?

Tags: c#, windows, tablelayout

when I drop a Listbox in a cell of a TableLayout, it has the properties for ColumnSpan and RowSpan ... but when I go to the code and want to say " listBox1.RowSpan " there is not such a property :( I want to do this because sometimes in my program I want this listbox to take one cell and sometimes I want it to take two cells. so How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the RowSpan programmatically, you have to do the following:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(listBox1, 2);
```

And put the desired number of rows where I put the 2.